# Luminosity of stars

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astrophysics, stars, luminosity

Good afternoon, I am attempting to calculate the ratio of temperature and luminosity between two stars, one entirely made of iron and the other of hydrogen, with the same volume.

To do so, I have employed
$$
m = \frac{1}{2X+0.75Y+0.5Z} m_H
$$
to obtain the average molecular weight (X=fraction of H, Y=fraction of He, Z=fraction of metals), resulting (1=hydrogen,2=iron)
$$
m_{1}(X=1) = 0.5 m_H, \quad m_{2}(Z=1) = 2m_H 
$$
Next, I have used that the luminosity of the a star is proportional to $M^4$ which is proportional to the average molecular weight so
$$
\frac{L_2}{L_1}=2^8=256
$$
However, I found it strange that the luminosity of an iron star is greater than that of a hydrogen star, which is entirely "fuel". I am not sure if I have made a mistake or if it is due to inconsistencies in the assumptions of the problem. I would greatly appreciate any clarification or ideas on this matter.

Comment: "the luminosity of the a star is proportional to $M^4$  which is proportional to the average molecular weight" - I do not uderstand this statement.

Comment: Hi, I assume that the mass of the star $M$ is proportional to the average molecular weight if there is only one component $M\sim m$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The luminosity of a main-sequence star is roughly
$$ L \propto \mu^4 M^3\ , $$
where $\mu$ is the mean molecular weight.

Your formula for $\mu$ is incorrect, it should be
$$\mu \simeq (2X + 0.75Y + 0.5Z)^{-1}\ .$$

For a pure hydrogen star $\mu = 0.5 m_H$. For a pure iron star $\mu \simeq 2m_H$ (actually more like $56m_H/27$).

The ratio of luminosities would be that the iron star would be more luminous by a factor of $4^4$.

However, the approximate proportionality you are using for the luminosity applies to main-sequence, hydrogen-burning stars, so it is not really applicable to your scenario. A rough understanding of why metal-rich stars might be more luminous comes from the core temperature being proportional to $\mu$ (from the virial theorem and perfect gas law) and that the opacity of the star drops steeply with increasing temperature, allowing efficient radiative transport of the flux.

Comment: Have you made a typo in your first equation? This paper https://www.astro.princeton.edu/~gk/A403/massive.pdf#:~:text=Notice%2C%20that%20luminosity%20depends%20on%20chemical%20composition%20not,mean%20molecular%20weight%2C%20the%20higher%20is%20the%20luminosity. suggests it should read $L \propto \mu^4 (1+X)^{-1}\ $,  That gives $L_{Iron} \approx 16 $ and $L_{Hydrogen} \approx 1/32 $ giving a luminosity ratio of $512$ or $8^3$.

Comment: Hi, thank you!! The relation that I've used was given by the lecture notes of my professor

Comment: @KDP That might be appropriate for $100+ M_\odot$ stars that are radiation pressure dominated and the opacity is due to Thomson scattering (which is where the $1+X$ factor comes from). The factor of 2 variation caused by $X$ is rather insignificant compared with the factor 256 due to $\mu^4$.

Comment: I still think there is an issue with the first equation. The luminosity is not proportional to the $\mu^4 $ and $M^3$ at the same time. That is 'double dipping'. $L \propto \mu^4$ or $L \propto M^3$ are equally valid separately, just using different parameters.

Comment: @KDP It's a reasonably standard relationship for stars where the energy transport is mostly by radiation. It is derived in most stellar physics textbooks (e.g. p.121 of "Stellar Structure and Evolution" by Prialnik). I am not sure what you think $\mu$ is, but it is unrelated to the stellar mass.

Answer (score 1):

[From LibreTexts](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/University_Physics_(OpenStax)/University_Physics_III_-_Optics_and_Modern_Physics_(OpenStax)/10%3A__Nuclear_Physics/10.07%3A_Nuclear_Fusion):

> Nucleosynthesis continues until the core is primarily iron-nickel
> metal. Now, iron has the peculiar property that any fusion or fission
> reaction involving the iron nucleus is endothermic, meaning that
> energy is absorbed rather than produced. Hence, nuclear energy cannot
> be generated in an iron-rich core. Lacking an outward pressure from
> fusion reactions, the star begins to contract due to gravity. This
> process heats the core to a temperature on the order of  5×10^9K  .
> Expanding shock waves generated within the star due to the collapse
> cause the star to quickly explode. The luminosity of the star can
> increase temporarily to nearly that of an entire galaxy. During this
> event, the flood of energetic neutrons reacts with iron and the other
> nuclei to produce elements heavier than iron. These elements, along
> with much of the star, are ejected into space by the explosion.

Unfortunately with the iron star you have picked a stage where the star has stopped 'burning' (no fusion or fission) and more or less at its dimmest and is about to go supernova and become the brightest thing in its galaxy, so saying anything about its luminosity is difficult unless the exact moment is specified.

Comment: The rate of nuclear reactions does not feature in the calculation of how the luminosity of a main sequence star depends on mass and composition. Though it is fair to say that there would be no "main sequence" for pure iron stars.